# What is registry setting to suppress "remote access warning" while debugging a WCF project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, remote-debugging

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution that contains a WCF service project.  When I am debugging the solution, the first time that I access the WCF project, I get the pop up message:

> "Security Warning: Attaching to a process owned by an untrusted user can be dangerous. If the following information looks suspicious or you are unsure, do not attach to this process."

If I click OK, I can debug without problem.  All subsequent access to the WCF service in that dubbing session run without the warning.

If I click on the help link on the pop up, it takes me to this page:

[Security Warning: Attaching to a process owned by an untrusted user can be dangerous. If the following information looks suspicious or you are unsure, do not attach to this process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/security-warning-attaching-to-a-process-owned-by-an-untrusted-user).

On that page there is a sentence that says:

> If you are debugging a legitimate scenario that causes this warning to appear, and want to suppress it, there is a registry setting that allows you to do this.

However, it does not tell you what that setting is or provide any obvious links to pages that might impart that information.  I looked through a lot of related pages on the site and searched with Google, but did not come upon the specifics of a registry setting.

Please, someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Visual Studio 2008 - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Debugger\DisableAttachSecurityWarning`
- Visual Studio 2005 - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Debugger\DisableAttachSecurityWarning`

See also [this blog entry](http://blogs.officezealot.com/mtblog/archive/2008/06/17/visual-studio-attach-security-warning.aspx).

Comment: This works exactly as I want it to.  One implementation note: the change to the registry must be done while VS2010 is not running.  It appears that VS caches the values from the registry and re-writes them as it exits.

Comment: Is there a fix like this for VS 2017? I check it but those reg keys dont exist.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for this fix for VS2015 and 2017, check this post:
[Where does Visual Studio 2017 RC store its config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119996/where-does-visual-studio-2017-rc-store-its-config/41122603#41122603)