# Where are the theme settings of Visual Studio 2017 located?

Tags: visual-studio, registry, visual-studio-2017

Where are the theme settings of Visual Studio 2017 located in the registry? I want to change them to enable the use of the Dark theme when running in Windows High Contrast.

The location in the registry has changed with Visual Studio 2017. Visual Studio 2012 and 2015 had their settings located in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio{version number}\Themes

Thanks,
Jacob

Comment: It is well hidden.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  Change the theme setting and have a look at the ProcMon trace to see what files/keys it writes.

Comment: This post will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119996/where-does-visual-studio-2017-rc-store-its-config It works for me.

Comment: My question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119996/where-does-visual-studio-2017-rc-store-its-config Thank you @Anonymous999.