# Disable security warning when attaching a process in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Does somebody find the solution for VS 2017, I tried to add the same key in 15.0 version without success...

Comment: Looks like Visual Studio 2017 keeps local registry, so you have to change this file and not the global registry. I fixed problem with Attach Security Warning just editing this local registry file. Read this answer for more explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41122603/692665

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into the question. I have rolled back your edit and posted the answer as a Community Wiki post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. First open RegEdit and load a private Hive in HKEY_USERS. Name it VS2017, for example.

   [image: regedit]
2. In the load Hive, go to : Software > Microsoft > VisualStudio > 15.0_5f0953ca > Debugger.
3. Create the new `DWORD` value : `DisableAttachSecurityWarning`, and set it to `1`.
4. Restart Visual Studio and test it.