# Visual Studio 2017 change %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-leak-detector

After installation and uninstallation of **Visual Leak Detector** from https://kinddragon.github.io/vld/ it left a lot of it's Include/Lib Directories at the default VS2017 settings.

That doesn't make any problem to projects, but I just want to know, how can I change it back to defaults? Google provided answers only for older Visual Studio.

Here are screenshots:

[image: Property page]

[image: Include directories macros]

Comment: Does this also happen for a new project or is this a project that got infected before?

Comment: Well "infected" is a strong word, but yeah, in new project it's the same, it stayed even after I completely deleted VS2017 and Microsoft Visual Studio folder in Program Files.
Also I couldn't find this settings in Registry or in files inside VS2017 folder.

Comment: Thanks for the direction! Actually it was in c:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props

Answer (score 2):

[Where does Visual Studio 2017 store its config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119996/where-does-visual-studio-2017-store-its-config/41122603#41122603)

In this topic (link above) it is told, that VS2017 now saves it's settings in a separate file.

But it also keeps this %AdditionalIncludeDirectories and %AdditionalLibraryDirectories in separate folder c:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\

Here is how **Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props** looked like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    </ImportGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros"/>
    <PropertyGroup/>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup><ClCompile><AdditionalIncludeDirectories>C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories></ClCompile><Link><AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\lib\Win32;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories></Link><Lib><AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\lib\Win32;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories></Lib></ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ItemGroup/>
</Project>
```

Also same in **Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props**.

So change the settings for whatever you want and that will change settings in VS2017 (I just deleted the folder).