# Cannot find the option data store registry location for an extension in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: registry, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, datastore, regedit

I'm trying to access a registry file of a customized extension installed in Visual Studio 2019 through windows 'regedit' for test automation purpose. But currently I'm unable to find any specific folder related to it.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-saving-user-settings-on-a-start-page?view=vs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019 it is said that I should browse to **VisualStudio\14.0\** in windows registries, but apparently it is for Visual Studio 2015, not 2019 version.

So I want to know whether the path to the option data store registry for Visual Studio 2019 is changed or different than the path mentioned as above, since my intention is to get the settings saved by the end-user in the extension that particular registry file.

It would be much appreciated if someone can come up with some solutions or insights to my problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119996/where-does-visual-studio-2017-store-its-config

Comment: Hi @PerryQian-MSFT yes the answer was a quite new learning thing for me. Thanks a lot. But unfortunately my intention was not fulfilled by this approach since it tends to be tech limitation. Thanks again and I will keep you posted for any requirement in future along this.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot find the option data store registry location for an extension
>   in Visual Studio 2019

**First**, thanks to Sergey to sharing the useful info.

Store registry of VS2019 is quite different from VS2015 and it does not show in the registry by default.

**For VS2019**, it stores under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx\privateregistry.bin`. And you can load it in the registry to get the value：

**1)** open the registry-->click on `HKEY_USERS`-->click `File`-->`Load Hive`-->select the related `privateregistry.bin` and name it as **VS2017PrivateRegistry**.

**2)** After that, you can see `16.0_xxxxx_Config` file under it

[image]

**In addition**, more info you can refer to [the link which Sergey provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119996/where-does-visual-studio-2017-store-its-config).

Comment: Thanks a lot fir this answer. Unfortunately my intention was not fulfilled by this approach since it tends to be tech limitation. I will keep digging with this method until I find a positive solution for my requirement. :) 

Cheers!