# Why is VS spitting random errors at me?

Tags: c++, dll

I'm currently writing a `.dll` in C++, and for some reason out of nowhere since yesterday, VS just spat random errors at me, from random C++ files and my `.hpp` files, and they have not gone away. I can still compile PERFECTLY fine, but it is preventing me from writing my code. Any ideas?

[image]

Also, I should mention that I have reinstalled VS, and the entire C++ language. Yet the issue persists.

Comment: Reinstalling might not fix the issue. VS stores it's settings in a seperate database file. Actually it's a windows registry file. It's in `C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio/<version>/privateregistry.bin`. Try renaming that file or moving it (as a backup) and see if the error persists. Your settings will be gone.

Comment: I don't have that privateregistry.bin file, nor do I even have that Microsoft folder in AppData/Local. I do have what you are talking about in AppData/Roaming, but no privateregistry.bin.

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using? Also I have found that compilers really get hung up on one error and throw ridiculousness all over the place afterwards. A single error may cause all following errors. Then again you said you can compile.

Comment: VS19, 16.11.0..

Comment: by all means it should be there... it was introduced with visual studio 2017. sorry I can't help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119996/where-does-visual-studio-2017-store-its-config

Comment: "*I can still compile PERFECTLY fine, but it is preventing me from writing my code*" - this is a contradiction.  What you have shown are clearly compiler errors, so the code is NOT compiling fine. Unless, is this coming from Intellisense and not the compiler, perhaps?

Comment: thing is, it  also works fine, no issues using the program whatsoever.

Comment: If those are intellisense warnings/errors close Visual Studio, delete the `.vs` directory where your project is, then try again.

Comment: I **do** have that file (`privateregistry.bin`).  In my case, it's in directory `C:\Users\PAULS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_1cc3c6ab` and is around 6MB in size.,

Comment: okay well., i found it and i did remove it from its spot just to see, and it did reset my settings, but i still get all the errors.

Comment: Try deleting the .vs directory in your profile. It contains some cache stuff and other visual studio related project things that aren't really needed for the project itself. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @FalcoGer already did that many times. no avail.