# Where to register CLSID entry for Visual Studio 2017 or later version

Tags: visual-studio-2017, clsid

For one of our project, we had created some registry entry  under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID<registry entry>
and some under specific VS version.
This seems to be working fine with VS 2015 or prior releases. From VS 2017 on-wards we have moved VS specific entries in *.pkgdef file. But we are not exactly sure about registry entries for CLSID. If we make under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\ it does work with VS 2017 but our doubt is on system where multiple instance of VS 2017 exist will it work ? Or we need to move these inside *.pkgdef file ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119996/where-does-visual-studio-2017-store-its-config

Comment: @HansPassant, CLSID on global registry does work for VS 2017, But I'm not sure in case of multiple instance. Wanted to get clarity that if we update HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\ will it work for all the instance of VS 2017 ? If not then how to define CLSID entry in *.pkgdef file ?